# Can I run a virtual machine or like a linux shell in a webapp/website or host it on a webserver?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vnc, container, gateway

I asked this question before and I am going to refine it so I can get a better answer.
I am planning to make a java webapp and I want to add a feature to it which is what I need help with.

I want to embed a virtual machine running an operating system or even just a Linux bash terminal in the browser. I have seen it on some websites such as immersivelabs.com where a user writes commands or does tasks in *what looks like* an operating system running in the browser and then you get points for doing tasks right.

In my previous question, I was told to check out Apache Guacamole, noVNC and Shellinabox. I want an idea of how I should set it up with a webapp. Should I make separate containers/virtual machines off and open gateways to them? I need at least 1 per user.
And are there any services that would allow me to host multiple containers like that? Something that can run on a web server or tomcat
Maybe even some API that I can run locally to try it out on my own system

I would appreciate any advice or guidance

Comment: Maybe https://bellard.org/jslinux/vm.html?url=buildroot-x86.cfg could be a starting point. It runs a GNU/Linux system in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The website you have mentioned, Immersive Labs, state on their [support page](https://www.immersivelabs.com/support/) that they are 100% cloud based. We can then reasonably assume that they have a backend system in the cloud, and that the application is not self contained in the browser.

So to duplicate this architecture, you would run a remote system and connect to it using a web interface. The remote system can be a VM or a container. VMs would be 'heavier' in terms of resources, but would provide better isolation between instances. Containers are the opposite - light on resources, but share some aspects. You will want to use one instance per user so that their activities are isolated from one another.

If you decide to go with containers, then you could use Docker directly to manage them. It even has a [REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) so that you can integrate easily.

For the frontend, you should look into the options already mentioned (Guacamole, NoVNC etc). Since you are planning to use Java, Apache Guacamole may be a good fit for you. You can see its architecture [here](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/guacamole-architecture.html).